# Access print process in flex

Tags: apache-flex

We have an option for print the component in flex. But i want to print the selected file from my computer location and print that one by one using flexprintobject.Otherwise do we have any other option to print as my requirement.

Thanks in advance for your needful help.

Comment: What's the question again?

Comment: We have to print some text using flex tool means , we can use flexprintobject class. Using this class we can print using the component value like datagrid,label or text. But how to print the pdf file or some other file which was retrieved from server location and sent it to the print from flex only? ........i cant find the way to do it?

Comment: I might be wrong here, but AFAIK flex can only print files, it is able to render as well. Especially pdf is a pretty tricky thing to do, as there's no built in support for rendering pdf. You can use StageWebView for pdf display or write an .ane for your target OS to render the pdf to bitmap. In general you might need to download the file to your local filesystem first, before you can process it. Sorry I can't help better.

Comment: Thanks for your information T.Richer.I will try is there any possibility.